# How can I use Google Maps to let people see each other's locations?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to make a program for Android, what take all people who use my program, on the map. And every other (who use the program) can see her/him. How I can do it?

Comment: You want to make Google Latitude?

Comment: No, I want something else, but ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to have a service up in the cloud. When the user logs in, the app pushes the current location to the server. Then the app pulls down from the service a collection of points.

Comment: So, I need to have an own server? Or Can it be make throught Google too?

Comment: You can use googles app engine as the server platform, if you don't have your server running. http://code.google.com/intl/de/appengine/